# Multivariable calculus & partial derivatives problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let  $$H = \mathbb f(S,V) $$
$$\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial S}S\sqrt{V} = \mathbb g(H) $$
$$\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial V}\sqrt{V} = \mathbb h(H) $$

Note that functions $\mathbb g$ and $\mathbb h$ should be expressed purely in terms of $H$, and should not contain either $S$ or $V$. Find an expression for $H$ in terms of $S$ and $V$.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a seemingly simple problem, but I am not aware of a structured technique to find $H$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well if you have $\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial V}V = \mathbb h(H)$ then there is a straightforward solution i.e. $H = logS/\sqrt{V}$

Comment: Okay, you have two nonlinear equations, but each is an ODE. Is $H$ a scalar function? Then in general, there is no solution at all: two equations with one scalar unknown.

Comment: Yes $H$ should be a scalar function of $S$ and $V$. As you say, the system is overdetermined. I was hoping there may still be a solution though, as is the case in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed that $g(H)$ is a known function. Hense you can express 
$$G(H)=\int \frac{dH}{g(H)}$$
and the inverse function of $G(H)=x$ can be expressed : $H=G^{-1}(x)$
Then :
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}=\frac{1}{g(H)}\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}$$
With $\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}S\sqrt{V}=g(H)$ :
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}=\frac{1}{S\sqrt{V}}$$
$$G(H)=\frac{\ln(S]}{\sqrt{V}}+\Phi_1(V)$$
$\Phi_1$ is any derivable function.
The result is :
$$H=G^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln(S]}{\sqrt{V}}+\Phi_1(V)\right)$$

THE SAME METHOD with $\frac{\partial H}{\partial V}\sqrt{V}=h(H)$ :

It is supposed that $h(H)$ is a known function. Hense you can express 
$$F(H)=\int \frac{dH}{h(H)}$$
and the inverse function of $F(H)=x$ can be expressed : $H=F^{-1}(x)$
Then :
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}=\frac{1}{h(H)}\frac{\partial H}{\partial V}$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}$$
$$F(H)=2\sqrt{V}+\Phi_2(S)$$
$\Phi_2$ is any derivable function.
The result is :
$$H=F^{-1}\left(2\sqrt{V}+\Phi_2(S)\right)$$

In fact, we obtain two distinct forms for the function $H(S,V)$. So, there is a condition for consistency :
$$G^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln(S]}{\sqrt{V}}+\Phi_1(V)\right)=F^{-1}\left(2\sqrt{V}+\Phi_2(S)\right)$$
This means that a relationship must comply between the functions $g$ and $h$  so that the above relationship complies.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that in the given context there is no way to identify explicit forms of $g(H)$ and $h(H)$. Hence the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Why do you say that the problem is unsolvable ? I gave the analytical solution, so it is solvable. The solution is : $$H=f(S,V)=\left( \int \frac{dx}{g(x)} \right)^{-1}_{\left( \frac{\ln|S|}{\sqrt{V}}+\Phi_1 (V) \right)}$$ where the exponent $-1$ is the symbol for the inverse function which argument is $\left( \frac{\ln|S|}{\sqrt{V}}+\Phi_1 (V) \right)$ and $\Phi_1$ is an arbitrary function. Of course, the function $g$ appears in the result because this function is involved in the initial equation. It should be a non-sens if the function $g$ would not be involved in the result.